# Openshift reset `route` config when change branch

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, openshift-client-tools, openshift-4

I increased the timeout in the `Route` yaml, but the settings are reset as soon as I change the name of the branch through the UI, not through the yaml configuration.

[image]

This is the annotation:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 5500ms
```

Is there a way to set the timeout permanently?

(Openshift 4.6)

Thanks

Comment: Please write more details e.g. steps what you changed, and I'm not sure what is branch in OpenShift.

Comment: @hiroyukik I mean I take code from `GIT` and change a specific branch through the Openshift UI. I attached a picture to the question.

Comment: I don't think those are related. I guess that the git branch could be a setting in a buildconfig and the route could be a route for the application which is deployed after the buildconfig finished. In general, buildconfig doesn't change a route resource. Is that route managed by an Operator? or managed by a pipeline? There are still uncertain information on this question.